# Rails image_tag throwing ERROR Errno::ENOENT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Started a new Rails project and set it up nicely but when I use `image_tag` to try display an image(magnum.jpg) present in `app/assets/images` I get an `ERROR Errno::EINVAL` error. Been on it for a while and can't seem to get past.
Rails version in use is 4.2.3

Here is my view:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <p>
    Magnum
  </p>                            
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <%= image_tag("magnum.jpg", :class => "img-responsive", :alt => "test image") %>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum
  </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
Started GET "/assets/magnum-2630b6237ccc91601cd5f59ac6653ea110dc75e787a38ef596c7
0fbbcfb7b3c3.jpg" for ::1 at 2015-08-20 23:12:52 +0100
[2015-08-20 23:12:53] ERROR Errno::EINVAL: Invalid argument @ rb_sysopen - C:/Us
ers/ollaollu/Desktop/Project/webstore/C:/Users/ollaollu/Desktop/Project/webstore
/app/assets/images/magnum.jpg
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib
/sprockets/asset.rb:99:in `binread'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib
/sprockets/asset.rb:99:in `source'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib
/sprockets/asset.rb:107:in `to_s'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib
/sprockets/asset.rb:154:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack
/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack
/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack
/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack
/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack
/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack
/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack
/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack
/handler/webrick.rb:112:in `service'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in
`service'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `
run'
        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `blo
ck in start_thread'
```

Gemfile lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.3)
      actionpack (= 4.2.3)
      actionview (= 4.2.3)
      activejob (= 4.2.3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.3)
      actionview (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.3)
      activemodel (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.3)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (6.0.3)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (6.0.2)
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.0.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.6.1)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.8.0)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.3)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.3)
      actionpack (= 4.2.3)
      actionview (= 4.2.3)
      activejob (= 4.2.3)
      activemodel (= 4.2.3)
      activerecord (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.3)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.3)
      actionpack (= 4.2.3)
      activesupport (= 4.2.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.4.16)
    sass-rails (5.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    sprockets (3.3.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.10-x86-mingw32)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2015.6)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (2.7.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    web-console (2.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (>= 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  coffee-script-source (= 1.8.0)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 4.2.3)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console (~> 2.0)
```

Comment: please post your gemfile.lock as I suspect this is a windows related problem.

Comment: @Kelseydh just added it

Comment: Just to clarify, the project was working until you added `image_tag`?

Comment: Yes and still works after but it just displays an empty image and then there's the error in the console. `image_path` just displays the image path. Tried passing `image_path` into image_tag but still no success @Kelseydh

Comment: I've dug around and I'm afraid I can't give you a good answer.  This appears to be a windows/ruby related issue.  I know this is not an answer but I do recommend moving to Linux or Mac for Ruby/Rails development because the ecosystem support for Windows is just not there.

Comment: @Kelseydh I'll keep looking. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to trace down the issue to Sprocket version 3.3.2/3.3.3 and the asset pipeline.

specifying Sprockets version 3.2.0 solved the issue